# Unknown option PlotJoined->True

Tags: plotting

I am learning Mathematica (10.0) and tried the following code:

```
   ListPlot[ { {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7},
               {5, 11}, {6, 13}, {7, 17}, {8, 19},
               {9, 23}, {10, 27} }, PlotJoined -> True ]
```

from [this tutorial](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ayg/CS590C/www/mathematica/math03.html).

However, I got an error saying:

```
ListPlot::optx: Unknown option PlotJoined->True in ListPlot[{{1,2},{2,3},{3,5},{4,7},{5,11},{6,13},{7,17},{8,19},{9,23},{10,27}},PlotJoined->True]. >>
```

After Google search, I saw [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html) that

> The PlotJoined option for ListPlot has been superseded by
>   ListLinePlot.

So I tried:

```
ListLInePlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 11}, {6, 13}, {7, 
   17}, {8, 19}, {9, 23}, {10, 27}}]
```

But this time, there is no error message, and mathematica just echos back what I entered, without giving me a plot as I expected.

Can some one please explain what's the right way to write this example code now?

Thanks

--Update--

As pointed out by the comments, I just misspelled and used a upper case `I` instead of lower case. Thanks.

Comment: 1. If you spell it correctly it (i.e. `ListLinePlot`) works. 2. `PlotJoined` was superseded in 2006 or 2007 so that must be an old tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Yes, it's an old one, but short.

Comment: You could also use `ListPlot` with the option `Joined -> True` instead of `PlotJoined`.

Comment: Did you simply misspell ListLInePlot with a capital I?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.

Comment: @Mike Although already deprecated `PlotJoined` was accepted by *Mathematica* 7.  Do you know when the option ceased to work at all?  I would like to add it to my changes-since-v7 post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it still worked in V8, although the option name is in red. It does not work in V9.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks!